# multiple preg_match print array matches to simple string

Tags: dom, preg-match, simple-html-dom

preg_match thus far returns an array like result. How would you display or convert it to a string.

```
<?php

    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('URLofPage');

    preg_match('/\<h1\>\<span\>(.+)-(.+)\<\/span\>\<\/h1\>/i', $html, $match);
    var_dump($match);
    $match = $value[1];

    preg_match('/\<div \"comments\"\>(.+)-(.+)\<\/div\>/i', $html, $match);
    var_dump($match);
    $match = $value[1];

?>
```

Returns a result of:

**array(3) { [0]=> string(77) "
THIS IS THE H1
" [1]=> string(32) "THIS IS THE" [2]=> string(22) "H1" }**

Thus far, I was only able to get the first preg_match to find and display info. Using two preg_match may be an incorrect method. Is there a better way of doing this? How would you convert the array to a simple string for it to be used as Find & Replace to a HTML template?

Trying to increase PHP skills this year. Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions to match content, check the simple html dom page for examples http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `implode()` function

Comment: Think str_get_html is what needs to be used.